# Magento 2 - How to create a shipping carrier?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping

I am trying to create a new **shipping carrier** in just like DHL, FEDX, UPS.
I am taking a reference of **Magento_DHL module**.
Can any one tell the required code needed to create a shipping carrier.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can simply review flat rate and based on that you can move ahead. I've developed extra flat rate shipping method in magento 2 but my gitlab url is not working.

Could you please review this so you will have better understanding

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-shipping-method/

Here Shipping.php model is the main in which you can implement your custom logic.

Regards,Sam

Comment: Hi, Sam, i have already followed this blog and created a shipping method, **i want to create a shipping carrier** that we can set when we are going to create a shipment for any order.